# Prove: A basis $G$ is a Grobner basis of an ideal $\iff$ for every element $S$ in a homogeneous basis for the syzygies $S(G)$ we have $S.G \to_{G}0. $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis, multivariate-polynomial

A basis $G=(g_1,...,g_t)$ for an ideal I is a Grobner basis $\iff$ for every element $S=(h_1,...h_t)$ in a homogeneous basis for the syzygies $S(G)$ we have $S.G = \Sigma_{i=1}^{t} h_ig_i \to_{G}0. $

This is theorem 9 in chapter 2.9 of Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'Shea. The proof given there is not clear to me.

Definitions in the text:

Let $F=(f_1,...,f_s)$. A **syzygy** on the on the leading terms $LT(f_1),...,LT(f_s)$ of $F$ is an s-tuple of polynomials $S=(h_1,...,h_s)\in (k[x_1,...,k_n])^s$ such that $\Sigma_{i-1}^{s} h_iLT(f_i)=0$. $S(F)$ is a collection of all syzygies on $F$.

An element $S \in S(F)$ is **homogeneous** of multidegree $\alpha$ where $\alpha \in Z^{n}_{\geq0}$ provided that $S=(c_1x^{\alpha_1},...,c_sx^{\alpha_s})$  where $c_i\in k$ and $\alpha_i + \ multideg(f_i) = \alpha$  whenever $c_i \neq 0$

We say that  **$f \in [x_1,..,x_n]$ reduces to zero modulo $G = \{g_1,...,g_t\} \subset k[x_1,...,x_n]$** i.e. **$f \to_{G} 0$** if $f$ can be written in the form $f = a_1g_1+...+a_tg_t$ such that whenever $a_ig_i \neq 0$, we have multideg(f) $\geq$ multideg($a_ig_i$).

My Attempt:

($\implies$) Given $G$ to be a Grobner basis and $S=(h_1,...,h_t)$ a syzygy of $G$ that is homogeneous we know that $\Sigma_{i=1}^t h_iLT(g_i) = 0$ and that $LT(h_i).LT(g_i)$ have the same multidegree for all $i$.

To prove RHS we need to show that multideg($\Sigma h_ig_i$) $\geq$ multideg($h_ig_i$) for all $i$ which is equivalent to showing $\Sigma_{i=1}^t LT(h_i)LT(g_i) \neq 0 $. But the above would imply that $\Sigma_{i=1}^t LT(h_i)LT(g_i)=0$.

What is wrong here ?

Help also in proving the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ S.G \rightarrow _G 0$ means that $S.G$ can be written as $\Sigma a_ig_i$ where multideg($S.G$) > multideg($a_ig_i$) whenever $a_ig_i \neq 0$. Here $a_i$ need not equal $h_i$.

This is all cleared up in the fourth version of the book.